# Does rel="preload" work with an HTTP server?

Tags: html, apache, http

If I have a link I'm trying to preload, e.g.

```
<link rel="preload" href="http://example.com/example.js">
```

and I don't know if `example.com` is an HTTP or HTTP2 server. Does the `preload` specification do anything if it's only HTTP?

Comment: Depends on the browser as well. Firefox team is still working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes preload can be used by both.

Some servers use the preload header to implement HTTP/2 push. See [here for an explanation for Apache HTTP/2 push](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/http2.html#push) and [here for how Cloudflare are doing this in a similar manner on a customised version of Nginx](https://blog.cloudflare.com/announcing-support-for-http-2-server-push-2/).

However there are also many use cases for using it outside of HTTP/2 by the browser. For example to preload fonts from other domains (HTTP/2 push obviously only works from your server) - that doesn't need HTTP/2 but just needs browser support - [not great at the moment as basically just Chrome and Opera](http://caniuse.com/#search=Preload) but [WebKit (used by Safari) have just implemented it so should be rolled out soon enough](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=165521) though [Mozilla/Firefox have not yet](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1222633) and [neither have Microsoft/Edge](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/7666725-preload).

[Smashing Mag have a great article on this subject](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/02/preload-what-is-it-good-for/) and why browser usage and HTTP/2 server usage complement each other and are useful for different use cases.

Comment: Please **[vote](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/page.cgi?id=voting/user.html&bug_id=1222633#vote_1222633)** for issues which you care about in the bugzilla tracker

Comment: Thanks for all the info! Glad to hear that browsers are implementing on their side so it's not 100% HTTP2 dependent.